# Python Matlibplot space between bar chart when the number of x axis not continuous

Tags: python, matplotlib

Finally i use `plt.xticks(range(1,len(x)+1), x)` to set the x axis

`plt.bar(list(range(1,len(x)+1)),y,color='lightgreen')` to put the x valus

Now whatever the x axis value is the bar space is average.

[image]

```
x=[1,3,6,9]
y=[2,4,6,8]
plt.figure(figsize=(11,11))
plt.title('Matlib Bar Chart',fontdict=font)
plt.xlabel('Num',fontdict=font)
plt.xticks(range(1,len(x)+1), x)
plt.bar(list(range(1,len(x)+1)),y,color='lightgreen')
plt.show()
```

====================

I am trying create a Bar chart where I use continuous numbers as X axis the bar chart have average space. But when I use random number as X axis the space becomes so huge. How i fix that, and how can I add the text on every bar chart?

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



font={'weight':'bold',
      'size':24,
     'c':'pink'
}
plt.figure(figsize=(11,11))
plt.title('Matlib Bar Chart',fontdict=font)
plt.xlabel('Num',fontdict=font)
plt.bar([1,4,6,9],[2,3,6,8],color='lightgreen')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: space is based on you input `[1,4,6,9]`

Answer (score 0):

Values of x axis are [1,4,6,9]. It happens because of your input. Try change the first input 1 to 3 and see the difference.

Comment: If not change the X axis how to fix the space?

Comment: // plt.bar([1,4,6,9],[2,3,6,8],color='lightgreen', width=1.8) // try change the width parameter in plt.bar as I shared. This isn't avoid the white space but reduce it.